# Azure SignalR on .Net Core Web API and Angular 12 facing 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, backgroundworker, azure-signalr

I am trying to connect my backend server on .Net Core to my front end on Angular using the Azure SignalR service. I am getting the following error

```
Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Unauthorized: Status code '401'
```

[image]

Here is my frontend SignalR service

[image]

In My Backend Program.cs I have added the SignalR Service and the CORS policy

[image]
[image]
This is my Strongly Typed Hub
[image]

I am adding its dependency to my Trigger service here using hub context. This trigger service is later added to a background process.

[image]

Networks Tab

[image]

So the flow is like this. Angular sends an HTTP post request, which sets the background service in motion. When the process completes, I want to send the push notification to the Angular front end that the process is complete using SignalR. I am trying to do that but am getting this unauthorized error for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending the token for authentication.

First you need to change the createConnection from Angular:

```
.withUrl("https://localhost:7226/hub/generation", { accessTokenFactory: () => this.loginToken })
```

this.loginToken is the token you send everytime for other api request.

Second thing to change (assuming your using JWT for auth):

```
.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["authorization"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/hub/generation"))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
}
```

Comment: Adding AccessTokenFactory in my SignalRService did the job. Thanks